# How do I change data of component according to property passed to this component

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuejs2, frontend, vue-component

I am trying to create a table component in vue which will change order according to a property passed to this component :

```js
sort: {
      type: String,
      default: "desc",
      description: "Table data order"
    }
```

if I pass here asc I want rows to be placed in a reversed order like that:
desc - [1,2,3] asc - [3,2,1]
So what I've done is just added a function which changes order of array in state data:
( that's where from I get all the data for rows )

```js
data: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
      description: "Table data"
    }
```

and it's actually work, but I can't get rid of feeling like I've done something in a wrong way and I would like to see your thoughts and solutions. Thanks in advance, whole component code is below.

```html
<template>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <slot name="columns" :columns="columns">
          <th v-for="column in columns" :key="column">{{ column }}</th>
        </slot>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="(item, index) in data" :key="index">
        <slot :row="item" :index="index">
          <td
            v-for="(column, index) in colsWithValue(item)"
            :key="index"
          >{{ itemValue(item, column) }}</td>
        </slot>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: "base-table",
  props: {
    columns: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
      description: "Table columns"
    },
    data: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
      description: "Table data"
    },
    sort: {
      type: String,
      default: "desc",
      description: "Table data order"
    }
  },
  computed: {
    tableClass() {
      return this.type && `table-${this.type}`;
    },
    colsWithValue() {
      return row => {
        return this.columns.filter(column => this.hasValue(row, column));
      };
    }
  },
   methods: {
    hasValue(item, column) {
      return item[column.toLowerCase()] !== "undefined";
    },
    itemValue(item, column) {
      return item[column.toLowerCase()];
    },
    sortDataAsc(){
      if(this.sort === "asc"){
      this.data = this.data.reverse();
    }
    }
  },
  created(){
    this.sortDataAsc();
  }
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure if that is the best solution, you can check the documentation about this "Displaying Filtered/Sorted Results" at the link https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Displaying-Filtered-Sorted-Results

The best example is:

```html
<li v-for="n in evenNumbers">{{ n }}</li>
```

```js
data: {
  numbers: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
},
computed: {
  evenNumbers: function () {
    return this.numbers.filter(function (number) {
      return number % 2 === 0
    })
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, don't know how I didn't find it in documentation earlier. All examples I found before didn't work for me because it caused infinite render loop. But this example is the best without any single unnecessary line of code.

Comment: Welcome! Also I have approved your edit suggestion.